# EventMachine unbind reason

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I am building a program with EventMachine and sometimes clients on weak internet will trigger unbind in our program. I was wondering how can I determine why the unbind function is being triggered and if there is anything I can do to help these weak clients.

Comment: Ehhm. Reconnect? https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/eventmachine.rb#L762 ?

Answer (score 1):

Unbind will be called when connection is terminated for some reason, usually you need to reconnect to server.

```
class MyConnection < EM::Connection
  def initialize(host, port)
    @host, @port = host, port
    @retry = 0
  end

  def self.connect(host, port, timeout)
    EM.connect(host, port, self, host, port)
  end

  def connection_completed
    @retry = 0
  end

  def unbind
    if @retry < 3
      EM.add_timer(1){ @retry +=1 && reconnect(@host, @port) }
    else
      fail "Can't reconnect"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

appears you can also define unbind with a "reason" parameter:

```
def unbind(reason=nil)
end
```

refs:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eventmachine/9HFuXS15HYg
https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/362

Comment: I looked into this but when I tried to use this code on the latest event machine gem, the reason stayed nil. Does it work for you?

Comment: if reason is nil that means "some other reason" -- you could ask the EM guys about it...